# How to avoid input value copying on click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Everything works fine but it also copies the value inside input button e.g if i write 1st in the input, 1st will also be copied on click of the button, does anyone has any resolution ?

```js
$(function(){
  $(".btn-copy").on('click', function(){
    var ele = $(this).closest('.example-2').clone(true);
    $(this).closest('.example-2').after(ele);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card">
                      <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Add Class</h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <form action="#">
                          <div class="example-2 form-group row">
                            <!--<label class="col-form-label col-md-2">Input Addons</label>-->
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                              <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                  <span class="input-group-text">Class Name</span>
                                </div>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text">
                                <div class="input-group-append">
                                  <button class="btn-copy btn btn-primary" type="button">Add More</button>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                          </div>


                        </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-copy").on('click', function() {
    var ele = $(this).closest('.example-2').clone(true);
    ele.find('input').val('')
    if (ele.find('button').length<2) {
      let btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.innerHTML = "Delete";
      btn.onclick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        ele.remove()
      }
      ele[0].appendChild(btn);
    }
    $(this).closest('.example-2').after(ele);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h5 class="card-title">Add Class</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form action="#">
          <div class="example-2 form-group row">
            <!--<label class="col-form-label col-md-2">Input Addons</label>-->
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text">Class Name</span>
                </div>
                <input class="form-control" type="text">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <button class="btn-copy btn btn-primary" type="button">Add More</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>


        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey actually i also wanted to add a del button, can u help me in that

Comment: hey thanks, but there is a issue everytime i tap on add more click me is multiplied

Comment: there should be only one click me

Comment: I added an if that prevents it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236581/discussion-between-aazim-khaki-and-vulwsztyn).